# Inclusion is a group isomorphism

Tags: algebraic-topology

I'm pretty new to topology and I'm having trouble solving some exercises since I'm not familiar with the notation used. First of all I'm not entirely sure what $\pi_1(X, p)$ means. My guess would be that it is loops with basepoints at $p$ belonging to $X$.

Here is an exercise I was trying to do but had issue since I'm having a hard time understanding what $\pi_1(X,p)$ and $G_p$ means.

Let $X$ be a space. Fix a subspace $Y$ with $i \colon Y \rightarrow X$ the inclusion. 
$$ G := \coprod_{p,q\in Y}
\pi_1(X, p, q) ⇒ Y $$

Show that the inclusion $G_p → \pi_1(X, p)$ is a group isomorphism for each $p \in Y$.

Comment: Can you say where you're getting this exercise from? Does it not define these terms?

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some conflating of different concepts going on in your question. The fundamental group $\pi_1(X,p)$ involves a choice of a single basepoint. Its elements are homotopy classes of loops based at $p$. That is, two actual, concrete loops are considered the same element of $\pi_1(X,p)$ if they are homotopic (keeping the basepoint fixed throughout the homotopy).

Now it is possible to form something called the fundamental groupoid of $X$, which involves homotopy classes of all paths in $X$, not just loops based at a single chosen point. This is something like your disjoint union thing over all $p,q\in Y$. But I don't think it's what you actually want to consider. Moreover, it's not true that the inclusion of a subspace $i:Y \hookrightarrow X$ induces an injective homomorphism $i^*:\pi_1(Y,p)\rightarrow \pi_1(X,p)
$, let alone an isomorphism.

But here's a repaired version of your exercise that you can prove is true:

If $Y$ is a deformation retract of $X$, then the inclusion $i: Y\hookrightarrow X$ induces an isomorphism for any $p\in Y$.

Comment: Thanks that cleared some confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I will guess at how you're meant to interpret this exercise and say what I think you're meant to do, but I think if you don't really know what $\pi_1(X,p)$ means then this exercise might be a bit advanced for you. Try to consult the source you're using to see how they define all these terms, and make sure you understand all of the lemmas and theorems they prove. If they don't define these terms, or if they don't prove anything, maybe try using a different source.

---

Here's how *I'm guessing* this is meant to be interpreted.

The *fundamental group* $\pi_1(X,p)$ is indeed the set of loops based at $p$ modulo basepoint-preserving homotopy, as Franciscus Rebro says. But also, the notation $\pi_1(X,p,q)$ is often used as the set of paths from $p$ to $q$ modulo endpoint-preserving homotopy. If a "loop" is defined as a path that starts and ends at the same point, then we have $\pi_1(X,p,p) = \pi_1(X,p)$ (i.e. they are not just isomorphic: they are actually *equal*).

Now I'm guessing that $G$ is a *groupoid*, which is defined to be a category where every morphism is an isomorphism, and that $G_p$ is just the automorphism set of an object $p$ in $G$. This guess is based on the fact that a topological space $X$ has a groupoid associated to it which is a generalization of the fundamental group, called the *fundamental groupoid* $\Pi X$: its object set is $X$ itself, and the morphism set from $p$ to $q$ is defined to be $\pi_1(X,p,q)$ and composition of morphisms is concatenation of paths. The purpose of the fundamental groupoid is to have a construction like the fundamental group but without having to choose a basepoint, indeed note that $(\Pi X)_p = \pi_1(X,p,p) = \pi_1(X,p)$. (Exercises for you: 1) show that $\Pi X$ really is a groupoid i.e. prove morphisms are invertible, and 2) show that if $p$ is an object of a groupoid $G$ then its automorphism set $G_p$ is always a group, and moreover that a morphism $\varphi \colon p \to q$ between two objects induces an isomorphism $\varphi_* \colon G_p \to G_q$.)

For your question, with $Y\subset X$ I think this object $G$ is the fundamental groupoid of $X$ restricted to $Y$, i.e. the object set is $Y$ but the morphism sets are still $\pi_1(X,p,q)$ (that is, the paths are allowed to leave $Y$, but they have to start and end in $Y$). Now, the inclusion $i\colon Y\hookrightarrow X$ induces a functor $i_*\colon G \to \Pi X$, and I think you're being asked to prove this functor induces group isomorphism on each automorphism group for $p\in Y$. But if this is indeed the setup then the exercise seems like a tautology: if $G_p$ is the automorphism group of $p$ then by definition $G_p = \pi_1(X,p,p)$, and as I said above this is actually *equal* to $\pi_1(X,p)$. In fact is seems that the functor $i_*$ actually induces *the identity function* on each morphism set in $G$. Without knowing how specifically $G$ is supposed to be defined it's impossible to say for sure what the exercise is.